# flutter-web-preview stagehead 3.3.2 not supported dart 2.3

Tags: web, flutter

```
[flutter-web-preview] pub global run stagehand flutter-web-preview
stagehand 3.3.2 doesn't support Dart 2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5.
exit code 65

[flutter-web-preview] pub global run stagehand flutter-web-preview
stagehand 3.3.2 doesn't support Dart 2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5.
exit code 65

[flutter-web-preview] pub global run stagehand flutter-web-preview
stagehand 3.3.2 doesn't support Dart 2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5.
exit code 65

[flutter-web-preview] pub global run stagehand flutter-web-preview
stagehand 3.3.2 doesn't support Dart 2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5.
exit code 65
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to downgrade the `stagehand`, I used this command:

```
$ pub downgrade stagehand 3.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Fix: Update Flutter SDK to v1.7.8+hotfix.2-stable.

I opened a question in the stagehand github, follow the link:
https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand/issues/617